# Consensus on a bug

Tags: discussion

In
[Why does this stiff BVP return unevaluated but a similar IVP produce a solution?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/208889/why-does-this-stiff-bvp-return-unevaluated-but-a-similar-ivp-produce-a-solution),
I addressed a somewhat common problem with `NDSolve`, namely that when the shooting method fails due to stiffness or a singularity in one of the trial solutions, the method fails with giving the user any clue except that stiffness or a singularity was encountered
(Most recently, it happened in
[Solving a steady-state viscous Burger's equation with NDSolve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/208838/solving-a-steady-state-viscous-burgers-equation-with-ndsolve).)
It does not say how or where the stiffness arises, and often it is due to a poor choice of initial conditions by the `"Shooting"` method.

1) I meant the post to address this specific problem about the `"Shooting"` method.  The recent, linked question in parentheses above has two questions.    So I hope it is not considered a duplicate, because I wanted a narrow question focused on a somewhat common problem with differential equations that I've seen on the site.

2) I think it's a [bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) principally because it leaves the user unnecessarily in the dark.  I'd like to seek consensus that it be tagged a bug.  I've reported it, but WRI may or may not agree.  Technically, one might say it is merely a suggested improvement. But I've seen several people waste their time on the problem without a clue how as to why `NDSolve` is failing or where to look for options and alternatives that might solve it.  For instance, the problem is not pointed out in [Numerical Solution of Boundary Value Problems](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveBVP.html); nor does the tutorial point out the possibility of using `ParametricNDSolve` to manually search for a solution.

My main point is to ask whether we should tag it a [bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug). The secondary point is to explain why I posted the Q&A, which might seem to some to be a dupe.

Comment: Whether or not it is a bug, the poor performance of `NDSolve` certainly reflects badly on Wolfram, Inc.  Although I do not use Maple, I surmise from posts on StackExchange by others that Maple solves ODE boundary value problems much better than Mathematica does.  For that matter, `DSolve` also performs poorly on many seemingly straightforward problems.  As @Mr.Wizard once remarked, Wolfram, Inc should stop adding new features until it gets the existing features to work properly.